# ImportError: No module named 'IPython.core.profiledir' in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When i opened a jupyter-notebook and choose new python file with python version 3.6. It gives an error but when i select python version 2, It works fine. I want to  work on python 3.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/deepface3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
ImportError: No module named 'IPython.core.profiledir'
```

Comment: Did you install `ipython` with pip3?

Comment: Yes, many times